# display all zip files in a list view

Tags: java, android, zip, filefilter, android-storage

I am trying to display all zip files in SD card/internal storage as list view. **I want only the zip files to be displayed and not any of the folders/ sub folders.**
I tried some code *but it displays all the folders containing the zip files,not individual files.* I dont want to display any folders, just the files .
How can I achieve that ?

**ZipFilter.java**:

```
class ZipFilter implements FileFilter {
    protected static final String TAG = "AudioFileFilter";
    /**
     * allows Directories
     */
    private final boolean allowDirectories;

    public ZipFilter(boolean allowDirectories) {
        this.allowDirectories = allowDirectories;
    }

    public ZipFilter() {
        this(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if ( f.isHidden() || !f.canRead() ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            return checkDirectory( f );
        }
        return checkFileExtension( f );
    }

    private boolean checkFileExtension( File f ) {
        String ext = getFileExtension(f);
        if ( ext == null) return false;
        try {
            if ( SupportedFileFormat.valueOf(ext.toUpperCase()) != null ) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //Not known enum value
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkDirectory( File dir ) {
        if ( !allowDirectories ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            final ArrayList<File> subDirs = new ArrayList<>();
            int songNumb = dir.listFiles( new FileFilter()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    if ( file.isFile() ) {
                        if ( file.getName().equals( ".nomedia" ) )
                            return false;

                        return checkFileExtension( file );
                    } else if ( file.isDirectory() ){
                        subDirs.add( file );
                        return false;
                    } else
                        return false;
                }
            } ).length;

            if ( songNumb > 0 ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "checkDirectory: dir " + dir.toString() + " return true con songNumb -> " + songNumb );
                return true;
            }

            for( File subDir: subDirs ) {
                if ( checkDirectory( subDir ) ) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "checkDirectory [for]: subDir " + subDir.toString() + " return true" );
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: you should post only part of the code which is cause list of file, so that we can focus on what you made wrong instead searching for the code

Comment: see `File#listFiles` method documentation